# Which SD card journaling file system for Windows and Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded

I have to make a choice between all SD card file system for an embedded device under Linux.

The goals are :

- Read and Write under Windows and Linux
- Journaling file system to prevent system crash or power failure
- Managed small files, i.e. < 4Go
- No need of high speed
- Avoid if possible driver or application installation on Windows
- Driver or application installation on Linux allowed

I always used Yaffs or JFFS2 on my previous systems but both file system are not compatible with Windows.

For the moment, my choice is NTFS but ntfs-3g support partial journaling: NTFS-3G supports partial NTFS journaling, so if an unexpected computer failure leaves the file system in an inconsistent state, the volume can be repaired

Thanks for your help

Comment: research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: You already received an answer https://serverfault.com/questions/1150630/which-sd-card-journaling-file-system-for-windows-and-linux

Comment: oBe why did you delete that other answer?

Comment: I have deleted the question because it was refused by serverfault.com :( So I have moved here! The only answer was "None, essentially"

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSL2 to access ext4-formatted drives; that should also apply to SD cards.

There's also an OpenZFS on Windows port, but I don't know how compatible the on-disk format is with OpenZFS for Linux, nor how mature [the code](https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/openzfs) is.

> Journaling file system to prevent system crash or power failure

Note that you'd often *avoid* having a journal in continuous operation of an SD card; you're incurring a write amount amplification, which will wear down your SD card faster. It's said, but I can't verify it, that SD card controllers are optimized to play well with exFAT file systems – which aren't journaling file systems, but as said, that is usually what you want on relatively low-end flash memory like SD cards.

Linux can read and write exFAT.

Comment: WSL2 is not possible because we can't install anything on the Windows PC.

OpenZFS for Windows is in Beta version.
Your comment about using a journal and wear donw SD is right!

Comment: so, exFAT it is. But WSL2 comes with many Windows installations these days, by the way.

Comment: according Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), exFAT "uses a single file allocation table and free-space map. FAT file systems instead used alternating tables, as this allowed recovery of the file system if the media was ejected during a write (which occurs frequently in practice with removable media)."

Comment: @oBe as said, exFAT was designed for SD cards, ignore what wikipedia says; obviously, the file system driver will commit the FAT and data writes in the right order; having a second copy is not really something that helps at all. Stick with it. Also, if you can't install anything on your windows, that's like one of three choices you have for your file system (FAT32, don't do that;  NTFS, don't do that if you need to interchange data with a different operating system; exFAT, do that.)

Comment: thanks for your help, I will test exFAT!